# Where should validation code go for UITextField?

Tags: iphone

I need to verify some user entry. I was thinking of adding it in this event? Also, how can I check to see if we are in a particular entry field ?

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create IBOutlet's to all of your view's text fields and compare them with the received 'textField' parameter.

For verifying a textField's contents, it would be better to use this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

From [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-SW5) documentation:

> Normally, you would return YES from
>   this method to allow the text field to
>   resign the first responder status. You
>   might return NO, however, in cases
>   where your delegate detects invalid
>   contents in the text field. By
>   returning NO, you could prevent the
>   user from switching to another control
>   until the text field contained a valid
>   value.